# Silverlight App runs out of memory

Tags: silverlight, memory

I am developing a Silverlight app that may use lots of memory (up to 1 GB). However, I am encountering an out-of-memory error when the total memory goes beyond about 800 MB. I have tested the latest versions of Firefox and IE. I would assume that I should not encounter this error when the total memory is less than 1/2 of the maximum (2 GB for 32-bit process). Would appreciate if anyone could shed some lights on this issue. Reducing the memory usage or going to 64-bit browsers is not an option at the moment.

Comment: How about running your application out-of-browser? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: This may be an option but I would like to find out why the app runs out of memory at 800MB instead of 2GB.